# in play framework, The file XX.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : The import XXX cannot be resolved in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework-1.x

I have a problem when i run the play work framework in elicpse:Compilation error, The file XX.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : The import XXX cannot be resolved in eclipse. But I have add the jar file into build path(it actually in lib diretory). And there is no "red x" in eclipse but compile error. the project can run properly but when i copy it to my computer and it occur this problem.(I have play eclipsify in the my computer) can anyone help me~

Answer (score 1):

I have solve my problem by myself! I update eclipse to the latest version of eclipse and I find that the project I used previously is not in the workspace diretory. So I move the project to the workspace diretory and play eclipsify again. 
The problem solve.